# why does array initialization in function other than main is temporary?

Tags: c, initialization, array-initialization

This is the code in which i initialize array "turn[20]" in main as well as in function "checkCollisionOrFood()",the four values turn[0],turn[1],turn[2],turn[3] are initialized to zero in main function,rest are being intialized in "checkCollisionOrFood()".This is where fault starts.when i initialize turn[4]=0 in "checkCollisionOrFood()" and then access it anywhere,it remains 0 in any function,but! when i initialize next turn[] i.e turn[5],the value of turn[4] gets depleted  .i.e turn[4] have garbage value.turn[20] is global variable,its index"head" is also global.I'm stuck with this problem plz help me get out of it.This is my complete code

```
#include <mega8.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short address[]=    {0b00001111,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,
  0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000,0b00000000};
unsigned short turn[20];//it is declared as global variable.
unsigned short head=3;
unsigned short colHead=0;
unsigned short rowHead =3;
unsigned short rowTail=0;
unsigned short colTail=0;
unsigned short size=4;
unsigned short foodx;
unsigned short foody;

...

unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood()
{
head=(head+1)%20;
if(turn[head-1]==0){
    turn[head]=0;
```

/*this is where turn[] is iniliazized and if i access turn[head] here i.e just after iniliazition then it gives correct value but if i access its previous value means turn[head-1]then it gives garbage value*/

```
    PORTB=255;PORTB&=~(1<<turn[4]);PORTD.7=0;delay_ms(200);PORTD.7=1;
```

/*by this statement i checked the value of turn[4] just after initilization of turn[4] which gives right answer and then after initialization of turn[5] and accessing turn[4] gives garbage.*/

```
    rowHead=(rowHead+1)%8;
    if(!(address[colHead]&(1<<rowHead)))return 1;
    else if((address[colHead]&(1<<rowHead))&&
    (!((colHead==foody)&&(rowHead==foodx))))gameOver();
    else return 0;
    }
if(turn[head-1]==1){
    turn[head]=1;
    colHead=(colHead+1)%8;
    if(!(address[colHead]&(1<<rowHead)))return 1;
    else if((address[colHead]&(1<<rowHead))&&
    (!((colHead==foody)&&(rowHead==foodx))))gameOver();
    else return 0;
    }
}
void main(void)
{
turn[0]=0;turn[1]=0;turn[2]=0;turn[3]=0;
```

/*these values of turn[] are not changed irrespective of where they are accessed.*/

```
while (1)
  {
  if(checkCollisionOrFood())
    {
    PORTB=(address[colHead] |=1<<rowHead);
    turnOffTail();
    blink();
    }
  else
    {
    PORTB=address[colHead];
    createFood();
    blink();
    }
  }
```

}

Plz suggest me to get out of it.

Comment: So much code... Can you write a small example which illustrates the problem? It will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: is PORTD relevant to the question? If not, it should be removed.

Comment: @shafeeq it's okay to have a lot of code (especially when it's all relevant), but your code is very poorly formatted and that is what makes this harder than it should be

Comment: @manu-fatto PORTD is only mean to check values od turn[head].

Comment: @shafeeq where are you seeing garbage? where are you using `cout`? or are you seeing garbage with a debugger?

Comment: @TaylorFlores actually i light led corrosponding to values of turn[head] and by that it is found that its value is not zero but comes out to be 3

Comment: @shafeeq I would just post the entire code

Comment: Or just post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The code does not appear to bear any relation to your question.  You ask about initializing temporaries in a function, but your code has no such temporaries -- you just have globals, which are initialized statically before main runs.  You talk about initializing things in main and checkCollisionOrFood, but there are no initializations there, only some assignments.

Comment: One of the functions `turnOffTail` or `blink` might be accidentally overwriting `turn` or `head`. The easiest way to check this is to re-arrange your global variables and see if something else gets clobbered.

Comment: @ChrisDodd what i mean by temporary is that value which i assigned to turn[] is no longer remains same as soon as i assigned next turn[].this assignment of value is temporary.As far as initialization is concerned my array turn[20] is not initialized and i have initialized turn[0],turn[1],turn[2],turn[3] in main.rest is initialized in checkCollisionOrFood(),which you are calling as assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you observer garbage in `head` this could easily due to accessing `address` out of bounds, as this is located in memrory directly before `turn`

Check the indexing of `address` to make sure you do not write beyond it's boundaries and with this overwrite data in the next variable, that is `turn`.

Comment: i checked the value of head and it is properly incrementing,moreover turn[] for head=0,1,2,3 gives right value as these values of turn[] is initialized in main.

Comment: @shafeeg Did you check address for proper indexing as well?

Comment: address! of what? head?
what is need of checking address of head?

Comment: @shafeeq: When referring to "address" I'm referring to the variable declared in you code as `unsigned short address[]`. I strngly recommend to check whether the array `unsigned short address[]` is indexed properly and not out of bound, as for example `address[9]`.

Comment: no,no address indexing is proper because wherever i'm using index of address it is incremented as index=(index+1)%8,so no chance for index to get more than 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned short checkCollisionOrFood()
{
    head=(head+1)%20;
    if(turn[head-1]==0){
        turn[head]=0;
```

You might have a problem when "head" is reaching "20". The value of "head" is then rolling back to 0, which leads you to test the value of "turn[-1]".

Comment: i have discovered this problem at head=4,so i hadnt reached head=19 and then facing problem which you pointed,but of course this would have been one of the major problem.thanks i will correct it now.